# ¿Como puedo seleccionar una fila y mostrar la foto de esa fila en concreto desde una bsdd en un label?

Tags: javafx

Hola chicos como puedo seleccionar una fila, y que esta me devuelva de la base de datos una imagen en un label,tengo todos los demás datos pero me falta la foto,que no se como sacarla. Estoy haciendo un controlador de horarios basado en escritorio, gracias de antemano !

[image: JavaFX]

La foto iria debajo del titulo Foto del Trabajador.

Pego otra foto para que se vea la base de datos y de donde viene.
[image: base de datos]

Este es el código gracias de antemano chicos.

La variable a imprimir la imagen sacada de la base de datos es un simple label.

```
@FXML
private Label lblfoto;

  try {
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT registro_y_login.id,registro_y_login.nombre,registro_y_login.apellidos,registro_y_login.telefono,registro_y_login.correo,registro_y_login.fecha_de_registro, control_de_horarios.dni,control_de_horarios.foto_candidato,otros_datos_de_interes.carnet,otros_datos_de_interes.disponibilidad_para_viajar ,otros_datos_de_interes.profesion,otros_datos_de_interes.departamento_asignado FROM registro_y_login LEFT JOIN control_de_horarios ON registro_y_login.id = control_de_horarios.id LEFT JOIN otros_datos_de_interes ON otros_datos_de_interes.id = control_de_horarios.id");

            while (rs.next()) {
                oblist.add(new candidatos(
                        rs.getString("id"),
                        rs.getString("nombre"),
                        rs.getString("apellidos"),
                        rs.getString("telefono"),
                        rs.getString("correo"),
                        rs.getString("dni"),
                        rs.getString("fecha_de_registro"),
                        rs.getString("carnet"),
                        rs.getString("disponibilidad_para_viajar"),
                        rs.getString("profesion"),
                        rs.getString("departamento_asignado"),
                        rs.getBlob("foto_candidato")

                ));

            }

            col_ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
            col_Nombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nombre"));
            col_Apellidos.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("apellidos"));

            table_view_candidatos.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends candidatos> observableValue, candidatos oldValue, candidatos newValue) -> {
                if (table_view_candidatos.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    lbl_nombre.setText(newValue.nombre);
                    lbl_apellidos.setText(newValue.apellidos);
                    lbl_tlf.setText(newValue.telefono);
                    lbl_correo.setText(newValue.correo);
                    lbl_dni.setText(newValue.dni);
                    lbl_fecha_de_registro.setText(newValue.fecha_de_registro);
                    lbl_carnet.setText(newValue.carnet);
                    lbl_disponible_para_viajar.setText(newValue.disponibilidad_para_viajar);
                    lbl_profesion.setText(newValue.profesion);
                    lbl_departamento_asignado.setText(newValue.departamento_asignado);


                }
            });
            table_view_candidatos.setItems(oblist);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());

        }
```

---

Gracias por responder tan rapido ahora me surge que cuando pulso la celda o fila no muestra la foto enel recuadro en el ImageView, pero la consulta la tengo bien formada y no da ningun error a la hora de lanzarla.
Ahora bien cuando pulso la fila, no saca la foto en el ImageViewFoto que es donde realmente debería de mostrarse. Que parámetro deberia de poner a la hora de hacer el getSelectionModel para que salga la foto ? gracias !

```
try {

        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT registro_y_login.id,registro_y_login.nombre,registro_y_login.apellidos,registro_y_login.telefono,registro_y_login.correo,registro_y_login.fecha_de_registro, control_de_horarios.dni,control_de_horarios.foto_candidato,otros_datos_de_interes.carnet,otros_datos_de_interes.disponibilidad_para_viajar ,otros_datos_de_interes.profesion,otros_datos_de_interes.departamento_asignado FROM registro_y_login LEFT JOIN control_de_horarios ON registro_y_login.id = control_de_horarios.id LEFT JOIN otros_datos_de_interes ON otros_datos_de_interes.id = control_de_horarios.id");
        while (rs.next()) {
            java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob(7);
            InputStream input = blob.getBinaryStream();
            javafx.scene.image.Image image = new Image(input);
            javafx.scene.image.ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setImage(image);
            oblist.add(new candidatos(
                    rs.getString("id"),
                    rs.getString("nombre"),
                    rs.getString("apellidos"),
                    rs.getString("telefono"),
                    rs.getString("correo"),
                    rs.getString("fecha_de_registro"),
                    rs.getString("dni"),
                    rs.getString("carnet"),
                    rs.getString("disponibilidad_para_viajar"),
                    rs.getString("profesion"),
                    rs.getString("departamento_asignado"),
                    rs.getBlob(8)
            ));
        }
        col_ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        col_Nombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nombre"));
        col_Apellidos.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("apellidos"));

        table_view_candidatos.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends candidatos> observableValue, candidatos oldValue, candidatos newValue) -> {
            if (table_view_candidatos.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                lbl_nombre.setText(newValue.nombre);
                lbl_apellidos.setText(newValue.apellidos);
                lbl_tlf.setText(newValue.telefono);
                lbl_correo.setText(newValue.correo);
                lbl_dni.setText(newValue.dni);
                lbl_fecha_de_registro.setText(newValue.fecha_de_registro);
                lbl_carnet.setText(newValue.carnet);
                lbl_disponible_para_viajar.setText(newValue.disponibilidad_para_viajar);
                lbl_profesion.setText(newValue.profesion);
                lbl_departamento_asignado.setText(newValue.departamento_asignado);

            }
        });
        table_view_candidatos.setItems(oblist);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convierte el arreglo de bytes (Blob) en un `javafx.scene.image.Image`, eso ya se puede mostrar en un `ImageView`

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(<Your Query SQL>);  
java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob(column);  
InputStream input = blob.getBinaryStream();  
javafx.scene.image.Image image=new Image(input);
javafx.scene.image.ImageView imageView=new ImageView(image);
```